# #include nested too deeply for simple C code

Tags: c, macos

When I compile the C code, but I got  #include nested too deeply error.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {

  if (argc == 1) {
      printf("Usage: %s NUM\n", argv[0]);
      return 1;
  }

  int n = strtol(argv[1], NULL, 10);

  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      printf("%d", i);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

That's the whole completed program I got, I am running this program in MacOS, but I do not know why it's happening, since I only got two #include here.

Comment: what does the error say? I've never seen an error that says "`#include` nested too deeply"

Comment: Are you sure this is your whole file?  You're not `#include`ing any other headers that you've authored?

Comment: @yano clang reports this error, from what i've seen.  perhaps others.  many times because of missing or incorrect `#include` guards but generally in user-written header files and not system ones...

Comment: @Joe interesting.. Ive hardly used clang so that makes sense

Comment: I can't repeat this with clang/LLVM 9.0 on MacOS high sierra...  The code above compiles and generates the expected output.

Comment: https://ideone.com/cDMUl3, it compiles fine on ideone - you'll need to give more info (compiler and OS versions) and even then the issue is unlikely to be solvable here because it isn't a program error (the program compiles fine).

Comment: Please show your compiling command. There are only two  #include in your program, but if you are using gcc, `-include` option will automatically added specific header filer to your program.